# Flip animation in Anki

Tags: html, css, anki

I have a question related to Anki software that I want to ask everyone.

I have a flashcard, front and back.

How can I create 3D flip effect between 2 faces with one button (Like Quizlet).

For example: I'll create a button, then I want when I press it, the front will flip to the back and vice versa.

[image][image]